Execution failed for task app:mergeReleaseResources
I have been trying to make android build in my react-native project using  ./gradlew bundleRelease but I get this error
> Task :app:mergeReleaseResources FAILED
ERROR:/Users/apple/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/ef7e3198104e6ed5b72438d3c2fc716c/transformed/material-1.9.0/res/values/values.xml: Resource and asset merger: Can't determine type for tag '<macro name="m3_comp_assist_chip_container_shape">?attr/shapeAppearanceCornerSmall</macro>'

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
> /Users/apple/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/ef7e3198104e6ed5b72438d3c2fc716c/transformed/material-1.9.0/res/values/values.xml: Error: Can't determine type for tag '<macro name="m3_comp_assist_chip_container_shape">?attr/shapeAppearanceCornerSmall</macro>'

I searched for the solution over stackoverflow. Found this similar issue with no proper answer:
For the record, i haven't installed or upgraded any dependency that can cause issue

You have not provided informations as well.
But from the error it seems your fail build is related to this attribute :
attr/shapeAppearanceCornerSmall

I don't have any attribute with such name and that's what causing confusion for me. Can you tell what's missing I have tried my best to show all information of the error

you are using material-1.9.0 try to update it.

Don't have that either.
